concerning errors when booting
I'm on Ubuntu 24.04, and whenever I try to boot from any USB, I get the following errors:
Error: can't find command grub_platform
Error: file /boot/grub/i306-pc/efi_gop.mod not found
Error: file /boot/grub/i306-pc/efi_uga.mod not found
Error: file /boot/grub/i306-pc/ieee1275_fb.mod not found

On the BIOS screen, I also see these errors:
ubsan: shift out of bounds in /build/linux6.0.0/sound/soc/soc-dapm.c:814:15
shift exponent 16384 is too large for 32-bit type 'unsigned_int'

These errors began appearing after I attempted to boot a persistent USB, which was actually an SD card using an SD-to-USB adapter. I created the persistent USB with mkusb, using the grub-n-iso method.
Here's the sequence of events:

I powered on the computer and accessed the boot menu.
I booted from the persistent USB.
During setup, I selected "Install Ubuntu."
The installation process gave an error about an issue with installing.
I then shut down the computer and tried again, this time selecting "Try Ubuntu." There was no error this time.

I'm not sure if the errors started before or after the first boot, but I initially thought it was normal for these errors to show up when booting from a persistent drive. I only realized it was not normal after booting a live drive to install a fresh version of Ubuntu on my Chromebook (Chromebook 11 3180).
Additionally, when I tried to install a fresh version of Ubuntu, it crashed before reaching the "remove installation media and press enter" screen. Despite these errors, the system does eventually boot whatever I am trying to boot.
I think I may have fixed the issue by using a different method with mkusb, but I am not 100% sure yet. The second set of errors is still showing up.
Does anyone know why this is happening and if I should be worried?

Also, it does actually boot whatever I'm trying to boot in the end

Please don't use comments for providing additional information. Edit your question (See the link below the question) and add new information including those we ask for in the comments. For example, which version and flavor of Ubuntu are you using?

Im using just the base version of ubuntu 24.04
